# Oracle named constraint in create table to set date to default date

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add a named constraint in my `CREATE TABLE` statement that will cause of my columns to default to the system date.  I know how to define a primary key constraint:

```
constraint cust_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (Cust_ID)
```

How do I define a constraint on `Hire_Date` that defaults it to the system date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default for a column.  But that is not a constraint so you cannot name it.

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  cust_id   NUMBER,
  hire_date DATE DEFAULT sysdate,
  CONSTRAINT cust_id_pk PRIMARY KEY( cust_id )
)
```

A default is not a type of constraint so you can't use the syntax for defining a constraint to define a default. A default is not an object type in the database so it cannot have a name. A default is a property of a column-- it can only be declared inline with the column.

Comment: sorry justin i confused you...how about this:

Comment: CREATE TABLE customer (
  cust_id   NUMBER,
  hire_date DATE DEFAULT sysdate,
  CONSTRAINT cust_id_pk PRIMARY KEY( cust_id ),
  CONSTRAINT date_default DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE( hire_date )
)

Comment: @GeoffreyDobson - That is not valid syntax.  A default is not a type of constraint.  You can't use the syntax for defining a constraint to define a default.  A default is not an object type in the database so it cannot have a name.  A default is a property of a column-- it can only be declared inline with the column.

Comment: so basically i just want to do something like

CONSTRAINT date_default DATE SYSDATE( hire_date ) 

can i do that?

Comment: @GeoffreyDobson - No.  A default is not a type of constraint.  A default cannot have a name.  A default cannot be declared out-of-line with the column.  You can only define a default the way I did in my `CREATE TABLE` statement above (or an equivalent `ALTER TABLE`).